# htaccess auth and deny together

Tags: .htaccess

I want to deny all request to the server except some ip's , but those ip's should show the auth dialog. What I have tried is

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
allow from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login Required"
Require valid-user
```

It works fine , but after user login it showing Internal server error(500). Any idea ?

Comment: So you want the browser to bring up the authentication dialog box for everyone, including those specific IP's, but you don't need to log in?

Comment: I just want to bring auth dialog for specif ip and for other it should show Forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine ;-)

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
deny from all
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login Required"
Require valid-user
```

Comment: He just repeatet `deny from all` instead of `allow from xx.xx.xx.xx`  - I don't get it...

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when there's something wrong with the `AuthUserFile` parameter. You can put any random path in your `AuthUserFile` and apache will be willing to go along with the 401 require auth part just fine. But when it needs to verify the authorization given to it (in your case, via a BASIC mechanism) it needs to actually check the contents of the file, `/path/to/.htpasswd`. Make sure that you have the correct path to this file and that it contains actual htpasswd data, generated using the `htpasswd` command or something equivalent.

Comment: but the login is working fine.. if i give any wrong cridential its showing errror... :(